# jqGrid td cell height with new line characters

Tags: css, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to help display some simple information from our logging DB to make it easier to filter/sort/browse our logs from a web front end. One issue I've had trouble with however is the following:

Log Messages are potentially long, and I want them to cut off and trail with "..." as just a preview. As per the documentation, I've made the following colModel with a class set.

```
colModel: [
        { name: "LogMessage", search: false, classes: 'ui-ellipsis' }
]
```

This works correctly to trim off longer text, however, when the messages contains new line characters the cell height still expands. 
How do I force the cell height to stay fixed?
Or is there an elegant way in jqGrid settings to pre-process the text and replace new lines with spaces? 
Or any other solutions. I've browsed the documentation for something on the latter but haven't been able to find anything.

Note: I've tried setting line-height on the cells, however, this just makes the text squash together and unreadable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for pre-processing use custom formatter [link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter&s%5b%5d=format).. so you can eliminate the new line and more with spaces...

Comment: Just the pre-formatting I was looking for, seems I managed to skip over that when reading the docs. Thanks!